# Foreach string occurrence

Tags: c#, json, string

So I would like to read out all occurrences in C# in one string and work with it. Means I need the position of the part string, but I don't know how. Example:

The main string can look like this:

> Currently there are %count{"only_groups":"1, 2, 3","ignore_channels":"1, 2, 3"}% supporters online, %count{"ignore_channels":"1, 2, 3","querys":"false"}% of them are afk. These are the active supporters: %list{"querys":"false","only_groups":"1, 2, 3"}%

Contentwise this string makes no sense, but I think you can understand what I mean by these strings. There are also more possible variables besides %count% and %list%

Now I want to keep all these variables and replace something instead.

I already have the following code, but it would only replace one variable and it would only recognize the %count% variable if it is completely lower case:

```
int pFrom = channel_name.IndexOf("%count{") + "%count{".Length;
int pTo = channel_name.LastIndexOf("}%");
string result = channel_name.Substring(pFrom, pTo - pFrom);
Logger.Info(result);

string json2 = @"{" + result + "}";

JObject o2 = JObject.Parse(json2);

foreach (JProperty property in o2.Properties())
{
    var pname = property.Name;
    if (pname == "only_groups")
    {
        only_groups = property.Value.ToString();
    }
    else if (pname == "ignore_groups")
    {
        ignore_groups = property.Value.ToString();
    }
    else if (pname == "only_channels")
    {
        only_channels = property.Value.ToString();
    }
    else if (pname == "ignore_channels")
    {
        ignore_channels = property.Value.ToString();
    }
    else if (pname == "away")
    {
        away = property.Value.ToString();
    }
    else if (pname == "querys")
    {
        query = property.Value.ToString();
    }
}
var serverVar = (await fullClient.GetServerVariables()).Value;
if (query.Equals("only"))
{
    channel_name = "User online: " + serverVar.QueriesOnline;
}
else if (query.Equals("ignore"))
{
    channel_name = "User online: " + (serverVar.ClientsOnline - serverVar.QueriesOnline);
}
else
{
    channel_name = "User online: " + serverVar.ClientsOnline;
}
```

I hope people understand what I'm about to do. My English is not the best

Comment: How do you represent percent symbols, like if I wanted to say “Save 50% on your purchase!” in your strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Regex.Matches() to get a list of all occurences.

This pattern will find all variables including configuration json:

```
(?s)%.*?%
```

Then you just need to extract the 2 parts out of the matched value.

This will find only the variable name within the matched value:

```
(?s)(?<=%).+?(?=({|%))
```

This will find the JSON configuration within the matched value if there is any:

```
(?s){.*}
```

Only caveat is you can't use % character anywhere in text outside of variables.

Comment: Thanks, this works great, but how do I get the point where the variable is in the string, so I can replace it

Comment: Regex.Replace(). It works as if you select the match with your mouse and write the replacement over it. Just replace the first regex pattern with anything.

Comment: If you don't want to do RegexReplace, you can also get the index and length of the occurence from every match and use normal string manipulation, just remember to process occurences backwards from the last one to first one, so that the indexes don't shift as you replace things.

Comment: I just found a mistake in their solution. If I have the following, the one for the value of %client% takes everything up to the last % character: 
```%client{"uid":"Cx6Vh0w8LTe1mvxQxueLnU6vw34=","afk_away":"true"}% | %count{"querys":"ignore"}%```

Comment: You're correct but the bug is in the first pattern, detects your example as single variable when it's in fact 2. Missed a question mark for lazy expanding so it took too much. Fixed it above it now detects your example as 2 separate variables. If it works, please mark the answer as accepted.